# Get item from Object ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin

How can I call the access_role in `OrganizationAccess` ?

This is the classes

**User**

```
class User : Serializable {
    var id = ""
    var user_organization_accesses: ArrayList<OrganizationAccess>? = null
}
```

**OrganizationAccess**

```
class OrganizationAccess:Serializable {

    var access_role = ""
}
```

What I have tried

```
  mUser = intent.getSerializableExtra(ARG_PARAM) as User // receive from previous activity
  longToast("Role is " + mUser.user_organization_accesses!!.xxx)
```

What should I write for the xxx ?

Comment: `[position].access_role`. But it makes no sense to say "role is X" when there is a list of objects that represent roles

Comment: @TimCastelijns Here the sample of JSON  `{"user":{"id":"16","user_organization_accesses":[{"access_role":"Manager"}]}}`

Comment: what am I supposed to do with that

Comment: @TimCastelijns I added `component1`. Not sure is this the solution, but I can get the access role now

Comment: Use `?.` instead of `!!` and your app will not crash if for some reason the `user_organization_accesses` is null.
You may need `toString()` for the `OrganizationAccess` to make it look readable in the logs. A `data class` may be used too, btw.
Call something like `?.joinToString()` if you like to present the `OrganizationAccess` elements nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it

```
 longToast("Role is " + mUser.user_organization_accesses!!.component1().access_role)
```

Comment: It is better to use either `data class` or implement `toString` int the `OrganizationAccess` class. 
Also, using `!!` is dangerous, it is way safe to use `?.` instead (and check for nulls)